# C# login Window Form cant load. Skipped loading symbols

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, symbols

I build Windows Form application in c#. The application works great.
I've added login form, but when i click the login button it stops inside the button click listener.
Here is my code :

```
 private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(Program.cs);
        sqlCon.Open();
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("dbo.login", sqlCon);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user.Text);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass.Text);
        da.Fill(dtbl);
        if (dtbl.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            DataTable dtbl2 = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("dbo.loginType", sqlCon);
            da2.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user.Text.Trim());
            da2.Fill(dtbl2);

            t = dtbl2.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("t is : "+t);
            if (t== "A")
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("innnnnnnn");
                this.Hide();
                AdminMainForm form = new AdminMainForm();
                form.Show();
            }
```

This is one of the messages i get :

> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

It stops at the if condition -> `if (t == "A")...` and 
every click just print to console my line

- `t is : A`

I check the case and t equals to "A". Also checked my stored procedures,queries and it's all good. 
Thanks for any help.
Michael.

Comment: Do you see the `innnnnnnn` message in the console?

Comment: no. it's not code problem, it something in visual studio i think, dll files , symbols , something like that. the code is fine

Answer (score 0):

When comparing strings use `if(oneString.Equals(otherString))`.

Full code:

```
using(SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(Program.cs))
{
    sqlCon.Open();
    using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("dbo.login", sqlCon))
    { 
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user.Text);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass.Text);
        da.Fill(dtbl);
        if (dtbl.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            //here rewrite code with using statement
            DataTable dtbl2 = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("dbo.loginType", sqlCon);
            da2.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user.Text.Trim());
            da2.Fill(dtbl2);

            t = dtbl2.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("t is : "+t);
            if (t.Equals("A"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("innnnnnnn");
                this.Hide();
                AdminMainForm form = new AdminMainForm();
                form.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Off topic: Also when connecting to database do it like this:

```
using(SqlConnection con ....)
{
    con.Open();
    using(SqlCommand cmd....)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Why you need to use this is because `SqlConnection, SqlCommand ....` is `IDisposable` and inside `using` statement you dispose it afterwards and that way you are freeing memory so no need to do `con.Dispose(); cmd.Dispose()`

Comment: The == operator is overloaded in the `string` class to call `Equals` so you don't really gain anything by using `Equals` here.  There is an overload to `Equals` that allow for passing a `StringComparison` to affect how the strings are compared, but since you are not using that overload, there is no benefit to using `Equals` in your code sample.

Comment: its something with dll files,symbols or something with the vs

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.
i used t.toCharArray() and then printing to console,it was one char "A" and 20 spaces.
the data type in db was char(1).
so i used char x = t.CharAt(0).

Comment: That's why I asked if you were seeing `innnnnnnn` in the console. It was never going into the `if` statement. Either way, I would recommend getting into the habit of checking first to see if you have a value and then trimming the values you get from the database.